# %~dp0\ shows error message

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is a simple question.

A while ago, when I was writing program, I wrote this:

```
set /p a=<%~dp0\a.txt
```

And this worked.

Recently, when I am writing program, I wrote this:

```
set /p a=<%~dp0\a.txt
```

And this didn't worked.
So I have to use THIS:

```
set /p a=<%~dp0a.txt
```

But it's mysterious. How can I use `%~dp0` without `\`?
So mysterious. Anybody could explain?
ANY help will be appreciated. Even Commenting.

Comment: The trailing backslash is probably preserved so that the following two commands were equal: `echo %~dp0%~nx0` == `echo %~dpnx0`.

Comment: Have a look at these, many different ways to construct a `%~` path or partial path extrapolation.  http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/percent.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this in a folder and run it, and look at the end of the path echoed on the screen.

```
@echo off
echo "%~dp0"
pause
```

You will see that it has a terminating backslash so a filename can be run against it.

In many cases in modern Windows two `\\` in a row in a path will also work, but not all the time.

Comment: Oh, I understand. It's still quite mysterious, but I know it now. But if `%~dp0` is a location, why shouldn't we use `%~dp0\ `? (Just like location\)

Comment: `%~dp0` already has a backslash at the end, so if you add another one then there will be two, and sometimes two in a row doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, just like when I use `set /p varname=<%~dp0\something.txt` doesn't work.

Comment: Actually, it does work. Try `set /p varname=<"%~dp0\something.txt"` with the double quotes which protect it against spaces and `&` in the path and filename.

Comment: Maybe it's another command - could you suggest one or two that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

Because %~dp0 is with `\`, you can use it without another `\`.